# Failed JUnit test when calling Stored Procedure with Spring

Tags: java, plsql, oracle11g, junit4, spring-jdbc

I am really new to Spring JDBC. I have 3 JUnit Tests which have no shared data (no before/after methods required as they have their own data in their own data files)

Each of these tests call a stored procedure inside a package. If I run the tests individually they all pass but running all three, one fails: (if i change the order of the tests in the class the failing one changes)

The call to the stored proc uses Spring JDBC:

```
 SimpleJdbcCall callProcedure = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName("ADMIN.CALCULATE")
                .withProcedureName("GET_TOTALS")
                .useInParameterNames("account_no", "request_list")
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .declareParameters(
                        new SqlParameter("account_no", Types.INTEGER),
                        new SqlParameter("request_list", OracleTypes.ARRAY, "ADMIN.CALC_REQUEST_TAB"),
                        new SqlOutParameter("response_list", OracleTypes.ARRAY, "ADMIN.CALC_RESPONSE_TAB"));
        callProcedure.compile();
        Map<String, Object> inputParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // set StructDescriptor and ArrayDescriptor
        genericTypeDTO.setStructDescriptorName("ADMIN.T_CALC_REQUEST_TYPE");
        genericTypeDTO.setArrayDescriptorName("ADMIN.CALC_REQUEST_TAB");
                   inputParams.put("account_no", accountNo);
        inputParams.put("clawback_list", genericTypeDTO);
        Map<String, Object> outData = (Map<String, Object>) callProcedure.execute(inputParams);
```

Below is the exception that is thrown when hitting **callProcedure.execute(inputParams)** for one of the tests:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call
>   ADMIN.CALCULATE.GET_TOTALS(?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count ORA-06512: at
>   "ADMIN.CALCULATE", line 2160 ORA-06512: at line 1

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to take a look at the mocking frameworks. It looks like your unit-tests are related to each other. Unit-tests actually must be unrelated, and you can achieve this by using the mocks.